# R: Update/generate variables without loop

Tags: r, loops

How can I generate or update variables without using a loop? `mutate` doesn't work here (at least I don't know how to get it to work for this problem) because I need to calculate stuff from multiple rows in another data set.

I'm supposed to replicate the regression results of an academic paper, and I'm trying to generate some variables required in the regression. The following is what I need.

- I have 2 relevant data sets for this question, `subset` (containing
  geocoded residential property transactions) and `sch_relocs` (containing the date
  of school relocation events as well as their locations)
- I need to calculate the distance between each residential property and the nearest (relocated) school
- If the closest school is one that relocated **to** the area near the residential property, the dummy variable `new` should be 1 (if the school relocated **away from** the area, then `new` should be 0)
- If the relocated school moved only a small distance, and a house is within the overlapping portion of the respective 2km radii around the school locations, the dummy variable `overlap` should be 1, otherwise 0
- If the distance to the nearest school is <= 2km, the dummy variable `in_zone` should be 1. If the distance is between 2km and 4km, these transactions are considered controls, and hence `in_zone` should be 0. If the distance is greater than 4km, I should drop the observations from the data

I have tried to do this using a `for` loop, but it's taking ages to run (it's still not done running after one night), so I need a better way to do it. Here's my code (very messy, I think the above explanation is a lot easier if you want to figure out what I'm trying to do.

```
for (i in 1:as.integer(tally(subset))) {
    # dist to new sch locations
    for (j in 1:as.integer(tally(sch_relocs))) {
        dist = distHaversine(c(subset[i,]$longitude, subset[i,]$latitude),
                             c(sch_relocs[j,]$new_lon, sch_relocs[j,]$new_lat)) / 1000
        if (dist < subset[i,]$min_dist_new) {
            subset[i,]$min_dist_new = dist
            subset[i,]$closest_new_sch = sch_relocs[j,]$school_name
            subset[i,]$date_new_loc = sch_relocs[j,]$date_reloc
        }
    }

    # dist to old sch locations
    for (j in 1:as.integer(tally(sch_relocs))) {
        dist = distHaversine(c(subset[i,]$longitude, subset[i,]$latitude),
                             c(sch_relocs[j,]$old_lon, sch_relocs[j,]$old_lat)) / 1000
        if (dist < subset[i,]$min_dist_old) {
            subset[i,]$min_dist_old = dist
            subset[i,]$closest_old_sch = sch_relocs[j,]$school_name
            subset[i,]$date_old_loc = sch_relocs[j,]$date_reloc
        }
    }

    # generate dummy "new"
    if (subset[i,]$min_dist_new < subset[i,]$min_dist_old) {
        subset[i,]$new = 1
        subset[i,]$date_move = subset[i,]$date_new_loc
    }
    else if (subset[i,]$min_dist_new >= subset[i,]$min_dist_old) {
        subset[i,]$date_move = subset[i,]$date_old_loc
    }

    # find overlaps
    if (subset[i,]$closest_old_sch == subset[i,]$closest_new_sch & 
        subset[i,]$min_dist_old <= 2 & 
        subset[i,]$min_dist_new <= 2) {
        subset[i,]$overlap = 1
    }

    # find min dist
    subset[i,]$min_dist = min(subset[i,]$min_dist_old, subset[i,]$min_dist_new)


    # zoning
    if (subset[i,]$min_dist <= 2) {
        subset[i,]$in_zone = 1
    }
    else if (subset[i,]$min_dist <= 4) {
        subset[i,]$in_zone = 0
    }
    else {
        subset[i,]$in_zone = 2
    }
}
```

Here's how the data sets look like (just the relevant variables)

`subset` data set with desired result (first 2 rows):
[image: subset data set (first 2 rows)]

`sch_relocs` data set (full with only relevant columns)
[image: sch_relocs data set]

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible example and the desired result?